# How to handle data in session when session expires?

Tags: database, session, cookies, redis, session-cookies

Let's say a account has a `balance` field, and we need to query and update this field frequently,

- so for better performance, get `balance` from database and put it into session, so that I update/get the value of `balance` from session, is this correct?

Assume I use Redis to save session, when user logged in, set a session with 'balance' key, and expire time 24h,

- I want to update the value of `balance` in database when the session expires, because it will be remove from Redis, and the value of `balance` in session and database is different, is this correct, the way I design the web application?

Or session info should be readonly, I should update `balance` value everytime in database directly,